# What continuous integration servers work well with ruby on rails 3 and mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration

I am using a mac as the server. I need something that works well.

I wanted to use atlassian's bamboo but my attempts have failed. The latest doc I can find on the topic is an old blog post. http://blogs.atlassian.com/news/2009/05/bamboo_customer_8.html which helps very little and results in the error:

```
...rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:900:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

I looked at http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=2918 which also appears to be years out of date.

So the question is, which Continuous integration server should I use for my rails 3 project, which I can run on a mac and use .rvm (today in 2011)?

Answer (score 3):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is always worked for me, you even have a OSX installer:

http://ingorichter.blogspot.com/2011/04/jenkins-osx-installer.html

Answer (score 2):

[CI Joe](https://github.com/defunkt/cijoe) works fine for me with rails 3 and mac.

Jenkins also seems nice, though, as Ed_ mentioned. Especially the part about the OSX installer.

Answer (score 1):

[CruiseControl.rb](http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/) is a CI written in Ruby and can be used for Rails projects.